# When does the global sections of a prescheme X over an other S equals those of S?n

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f=(\varphi,\theta):X\longrightarrow S$ a morphism of preschemes whith $\varphi$ surjective. Let $\theta(S):\Gamma(S,O_S)\longrightarrow \Gamma(S,f_* O_X)=\Gamma(\varphi^{-1}(S),O_X)=\Gamma(X,O_X)$.
What conditions can we put on $f$ in order to get that the morphism $\theta(S)$ is
(1) injective
(2) surjective if it is already injective (and so bijective)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obligatory tautological answer: since $f$ includes the data of $\theta$, it's necessary and sufficient to require that $\theta(S)$ is injective (resp. surjective).

Since you're trying to extract information about $\theta(S)$, my guess is that you actually want conditions on $\varphi$, $S$, and/or $X$, which don't specifically refer to $\theta$.

### Injectivity

Suppose $I$ is the kernel of $\theta(S)$. Then the morphism $X\to Spec(O_S(S))$ factors through the closed subscheme $Spec(O_S(S)/I)$. Since $X\to S$ is surjective, this closed subscheme must contain the image of $S$ (set theoretically). The closure of the image of $S$ in $Spec(O_S(S))$ is all of $Spec(O_S(S))$,<sup>†</sup> so $Spec(O_S(S)/I)$ must be set-theoretically equal to $Spec(O_S(S))$, so $I$ is contained in every prime of $O_S(S)$, so it is in the nilradical.

> In particular, if $S$ is reduced, $\theta(S)$ is injective.

Note that we didn't actually need $\varphi$ surjective, just that the closure of the image is all of $S$. Since composing $X\to S$ with a nilpotent thickening of $S$ doesn't change $X$ or $\phi$ at all, I imagine you can't get a better condition than this without saying something directly about $\theta$.

<sup>†</sup> If $S$ is quasi-compact and 
its image in $Spec(O_S(S))$ is contained in the complement of some basic open neighborhood $D(f)$, then $f\in O_S(S)$ vanishes at every point of $S$, so $f$ is nilpotent on any affine open subscheme of $S$. Since $S$ is quasi-compact, there is a single $n$ such that $f^n$ is identically zero on $S$. Since $f$ is nilpotent, $D(f)=D(f^n)\subseteq Spec(O_S(S))$ is empty. So the image of $S$ is not in the complement of any non-empty open subset of $Spec(O_S(S))$.

There must be a way to show this without assuming quasi-compactness of $S$, but I don't see it right now. Suppose $S\to Spec(O_S(S))$ *set theoretically* factors through a closed subset $Z$. Why must there be a *closed subscheme* structure on $Z$ so that $S$ factors scheme theoretically through $Z$? A scheme theoretic factorization of $S$ through $Spec(O_S(S)/I)$ amounts to a factorization of the identity map $O_S(S)\to O_S(S)$ through the quotient $O_S(S)\to O_S(S)/I$, which cannot happen unless $I=0$.

### Surjectivity

I can't think of a good condition to ensure surjectivity that isn't essentially tautological.

There's no condition you can put on $\varphi$ or the underlying topological space of $X$. If $S=Spec(k)$ with $k$ a field, you could take $X$ to be a projective or affine curve over $S$. These two curves are homeomorphic, yet you have a surjection in one case but not the other.

A necessary but insufficient condition for isomorphism is that $S$ have as many connected components as $X$, since connected components correspond to irreducible idempotents in the ring of regular functions.

Note that if $X$ and $S$ are arbitrary projective schemes over a field, then any morphism between them induces an isomorphism on global regular functions. Any Stein morphism $f\colon X\to S$ obviously makes $\theta(S)$ an isomorphism. Is there an example of a surjective non-Stein $f$ which makes $\theta(S)$ an isomorphism?

Comment: Dear Anton, my question is about (as it says) putting conditions on $f$ not on $X$ nor $S$. Don't understand why you exclude putting constraints on $\theta(S)$. "Stein morphism" is a good answer(even if I don't know why it is so obvious). Is it true that if $f$ is flat with reduced and connected fibers then $\theta(S)$ is injective? What happens if one adds that $f$ is projective?


Comment: What sorts of constraints on $\theta(S)$ are you willing to allow? In other words, why is the tautological answer not good enough?

Comment: A morphism $f$ is *Stein* if $f_*(O_X)\cong O_S$. Since global sections don't change when you push sheaves forward, you get an isomorphism on global sections of $O_X$ and $O_S$.

Comment: Requiring $f$ flat with reduced and connected fibers might do the trick. I don't have much time now, but I'll think about it some more later. I'm pretty sure projective morphisms with connected fibers are Stein.

Comment: You are definitely right; my question is badly posed and the tautological answer is perfect. I should have added something vague as "traditional way to ensure that..." or you should have stopped after your tautological answer and I would have correct the question. Where could I find a study of Stein morphism with interactions between them and primitive one as projective, proper, with fibers...?

Comment: Is being a Stein-morphism stable by any change of the base $S$?

Comment: Your sarcasm doesn't carry well over the internet; I get the feeling that you're simultaneously asking me to invest more time in helping you and mocking me for the time I've already put in. Projective morphisms with connected fibers can definitely fail to be Stein if the base is non-reduced (maybe other times too). I can't think of a reference for Stein morphisms. It may help to search for "Stein factorization" instead. The Stein factorization of a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is $X\to Spec_Y(f_∗O_X)\to Y$. The first morphism is Stein and the second is affine. Stein is stable under *flat* base change.

Comment: There was no sarcasm. Thank you Anton for your answers. 